# Saving a CloudObject : Bad Request Exception thrown

Tags: android, mbaas

I began to use CloudBoost yesterday. In order to learn how to use it, i decide to save a sample Cloud object like this :

```
try{
                    final CloudObject obj = new CloudObject("Truc");
                    obj.set("col",2);
                    new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try{
                            obj.save(new CloudObjectCallback()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void done(CloudObject x, CloudException t) throws CloudException
                                {
                                    if (x != null){
                                        System.out.println("x != null");
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        System.out.println("x == null");
                                    }
                                    if (t == null)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("<<OK>>");
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        System.out.println("t != null");
                                        t.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }catch (CloudException e){
                            System.out.println("inner CloudException thrown");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }catch (CloudException e){
                System.out.println("outter CloudException thrown");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But this code thrown me a CloudException : Bad Request. Why and how fix this problem?

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

This issues is caused by a wrong `app_id` and `client_key` combination, wrong datatype in table column, or even an in existent `CloudTable` you are trying to save to.

Comment: The problem is fixed ! Thank you !